# Getting a distinct list with addition of the totals

Tags: c#

I have a list of string items declared like this:

```
List<string> methodList = new List<string>();
```

I do what I need to get done and the results are something like this:

```
Method1;15
Method2;30
Method3;45
Method1;60
```

I need to loop through this list and display a distinct list and the addition of the totals.  Something like this:

```
Method1 75
Method2 30
Method3 45
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do this, you'll need to split this up, then sum:

```
 var results = methodList
                   .Select(l => l.Split(';'))
                   .GroupBy(a => a[0])
                   .Select(g => 
                       new 
                       {
                           Group = g.Key, 
                           Count = g.Count(),
                           Total = g.Sum(arr => Int32.Parse(arr[1])) 
                       });

 foreach(var result in results)
      Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", result.Group, result.Count, result.Total);
```

Comment: How would I modify the above code to display the count of the method names, like: Method1 2 75?  2 being the count how many times Method1 occurred in the list.  75 is the total.

Comment: @Brendan: Just updated the answer to include counts for you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work:

```
var sumList = methodList.Select( x=> 
    {
        var parts = x.Split(';');
        return new
        {
            Method = parts [0],
            Cost = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1])
        };
    })
    .GroupBy( x=> x.Method)
    .Select( g=> new { Method = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum( x=> x.Cost) })
    .ToList();

foreach(var item in sumList)
    Console.WriteLine("Total for {0}:{1}", item.Method, item.Sum);
```

A better approach would be to keep the individual methods and their cost in a strongly typed class, so you don't have to do string parsing to operate them:

```
public class MethodCost
{
    public string MethodName { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use a `List<MethodCost>` instead and have direct access to the cost - use strings for presentation (i.e. writing to the console), not for internal storage when it is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
var result = methodList
    .Select(
        x =>
        {
            var items = x.Split(';');
            return new { Name = items[0], Value = Int32.Parse(items[1]) };
        })
    .GroupBy(pair => pair.Name)
    .Select(
        grouping =>
        {
            var sum = grouping.Sum(x => x.Value);
            return String.Format("{0} {1}", grouping.Key, sum);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another, slightly compacter variant is

```
var results = from item in methodList 
              let parts = item.Split(';') 
              group Int32.Parse(parts[1]) by parts[0];
foreach(var item in results)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.Key, item.Sum());
```